# can you simplified this natural log expression? $-\ln(1+e^{-x})$

Tags: calculus

I am doing Calculus 2 right now and wondering how can I simplify an answer, the result is at the top but can I further simplify like I did below?

$$-\ln(1+e^{-x})$$

$$\ln(1+e^{-x})^{-1}$$

$$\ln(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}})$$

From here can I bring the $e^{-x}$ to the top?

thanks!

Comment: I think those are pretty much simplified already. Do you need it written differently as part of some other problem? If so please clarify, otherwise I think there's not much else to say here. (One think you can do, of course, is rationalize the denominator and use $\ln$ properties, but I wouldn't call that simplifying.)

Comment: @runway44: I don't see an opportunity for "rationalizing the denominator" here, though you could trade the $e^{-x}$ for two $e^x$'s, by multiplying top and bottom by $e^x$. Is that what you're referring to? That's sometimes a useful trick, but here, yeah, I agree, the expression is pretty much as simple as it can get.

Comment: Right, rationalizing was the wrong term, but you got what I meant. :)